# How to access object properties in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am passing an object(model) in View where I have javascript code written. The object has certain properties that I want to access in javascript in order to create a drop down list from the values of those properties.
Here is my object:

```
public class TestObject
{
    public BuildData ExteriorColor { get; set; }
    public BuildData InteriorColor { get; set; }
 }
```

and

```
public class BuildData
{
    public List<ExteriorInteriorData> Data { get; set; }
    public bool isInstalled { get; set; }
    public BuildData()
    {
        Data = new List<ExteriorInteriorData>();
    }
}
```

Now in the View I have an object of `TestObject` through `ViewData` and I want to populate the values present in `List<ExteriorInteriorData>` in a select list.
Basically I want to do something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.ExteriorColor.Data.length; i++) {
            $("#Exterior_Color").append($("<option " + (i == 0 ? "selected" : "") + "></option>").val(data.ExteriorColor.Data[i].ColorName + ", " + data.ExteriorColor.Data[i].RgbValue).html(data.ExteriorColor.Data[i].ColorName));
    }
```

So, How do I access the object `TestObject` present in `Viewdata` inside of Javascript?

Comment: since this is MVC you could just use a loop in Razor to do this, no need for Javascript by the looks of it.

Comment: Using javascript for this is crazy (do some basic reasearch on creating a dropdownlist in MVC using the `@Html.DropDownListFor()` method). But to answer your question - `var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))` converts you model to a javascript object.

Comment: https://dotnetnsqlcorner.blogspot.in/2014/01/accessing-model-property-in-mvc-view.html

Comment: @ADyson How do I access the id of the select list by ID in the razor query?

Comment: @Nirman I am not passing the value in Model, it is in ViewData. So, how do I get the value from there

Comment: @testsys123 you don't, you embed the razor code within the `<select>` tags in order to write the options.

Comment: it should be simply - '@ViewData["ViewDataName"]'

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks mate, your idea worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are writing JavaScript in same view then you just need to convert your model object in js object using this code.

```
var jsModel = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))
```

if you want in external file then create an html element and set this model in data- field and get this model in js like this

**View**

```
<div data-JsObject="@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))" id="JSOBJ"> </div>
```

**JS External file**

```
var list = JSON.parse($("#JSOBJ").data("JsObject"))
```

I hope it'll work for you.

Answer (score 0):

except of javascript you can use defualt razor helper for create dropdownlist :

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ExteriorColor.Data, new SelectList(Model.ExteriorColor.Data, "Value", "Text"))
```

repale Value and Text By properties in ExteriorInteriorData

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Use for loop within the  tag.

```
@model [yourproject].Models.TestObject
<select id="Exterior_Color" name="Exterior_Color">
    @foreach (var item in this.Model.ExteriorColor)
    {
        <option value="@item.RgbValue">@item.ColorName</option>
    }
</select>
```

You can simply get selected item from javasrcipt

```
$("#Exterior_Color").val();
```